# how can I keep a reference for function's old prototype method while override it with a new method?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

For example, in Function's object it has `Function.prototype.toString` method. I would like to modify its logic with a new toString method like:

```js
function foo() {}
foo.prototype.toString = function() {}
const newFoo = new foo();
```

Then if I want to keep the original `foo.prototype.toString` method and used in the new logic, how can I do that?

This is the example I want to use it in new logic:

```js
function foo() {}
const originalToString = foo.prototype.toString;
foo.prototype.toString = function() {
 return `new toString: ${this.originalToString()}`
}
const newFoo = new foo();
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post and show an example of how you’re going to use the new method and the old method? This really looks like an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905). Why not accept a function argument in `toString`, or use separate classes, or use [`call`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)?

Comment: `let originalToString = foo.prototype.toString`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon sure, I just added the modify logic I want to use. And this is not working is because of the object reference i believe

Comment: Oh, so you want to wrap the method! Then use `originalToString.call(this)`, as suggested.